# Image Binding with UriSource from the user Picture library Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1

I can't seem to get images to display in a gridview from the picture library using the UriSource binding

Here is the XAML binding:

```
                    <Border Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                        <Image Stretch="UniformToFill">
                            <Image.Source>
                                <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding Path=ImageUri}" DecodePixelWidth="200"  />
                            </Image.Source>
                        </Image>
                    </Border>
```

and this is an example URI that I am feeding into it:

{C:\Users\Name\Pictures\Desktop Wallpapers\35bd31e7-5e4d-43c4-b704-136ee0b5b705.jpg}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass an absolute path in Windows 8 store apps.
Try to load your picture into a stream such as FileRandomAccessStream using FileOpenPicker
Create a BitmapImage and set the stream as source for the bitmap image and assign it as image source to your image control.

```
BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
if (file != null)
{
    FileRandomAccessStream stream = (FileRandomAccessStream)await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
    bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);
}

ImageUri = bitmapImage;
```

Comment: That is not an acceptable option in my case. Come on, It can't be the only way...